# Should I followup after 8 business days, interview went so well?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, communication, job-search, hiring-process

I gave a interview at a great company on 21st May so technically its been 8 business days. The interview went great. I gave 2 interviews: one phone interview and final in-person interview.

The first interview went really well that it went from 1 (it was suppose to be 1 hour only) to 3 hours of technical questions (problem solving interview questions) and 2nd round (final round) went about 4 to 5 hrs where each person from team or associated team took 1 hr each. The interview went really well and got a feeling at the end of it that I will get the job.

The tech lead with whom I communicated throughout the process asked me if I had other job offers and also mentioned that I was even confident interviewee than himself. I was able to reply with all tech questions along with behavioral. I also knew the 2nd interviewer as she seen me won in events as I interned with the company before.

After the first interview and before 2nd interview, I was asked to fill the employee application form and get 2 ID's for CRC [criminal reference check]. He mentioned that if they decide to move forward with offer then they dont want to call me again and save my visit hence I filled everything. I wonder if they do with all candidates as CRC is only done if they decide to give me a offer. What do you guys think?

While leaving, I asked about getting back to me and he said it would take may be 1 or 2 or 3 weeks. It depends on management. This doesnt tell me anything but I am wondering if I should follow up and what do you guys generally think.

The company and the team was so great. All of them were great with me and aspire to become such great developers like them.

Comment: How is May 28th to June 3rd 8 business days? By my count it's 5 days, if you include May 28th and today.

Comment: "asked me if I had other job offers", what did you answer? If you said no this means they don't have a rush. It can often be beneficial to imply you are talking to other companies and have a deadline.

Answer (score 4):

As with all job searches, until you have something in hand, you should move on and continue your search. Assuming you have done that, I would at least wait until the beginning of the 4th week, before contacting them. Since the indication you were given was up to three weeks, contacting before then is unnecessary, *unless* you have another offer in hand, and would prefer to work for this company. Then a single contact call, asking on timeline as you have another offer but really like this company and the position, could be in order.

Until such time, go on about your day, nothing to see here. Even the best interviews don't always end up the way we would like. (experience talking here :D)

Comment: 3 weeks seems rather long for such things, but given that that's what they said, I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: The 3 weeks could be because they have multiple interviews still scheduled and won't make a decision until after the last candidate - whatever the reason, you should wait until the time they have specified (maybe with an extra day or so).

Comment: It does seem a bit long, but as @HorusKol noted, they could still have multiple interview scheduled that the OP didn't know about. So patience is the watchword in these things.

Answer (score 1):

> I gave a interview at a great company on 28th May so technically its
>   been 8 business days. The interview went great. I gave 2 interviews:
>   one phone interview and final in-person interview.

Was this in the U.S.? Or in the U.K.? Or elsewhere?

The reason being is in general I would say yes, you can touch base 8 days after an interview even if they say “1 or 2 or 3 weeks.” But that said, last week—beginning on May 26th—was Memorial Day week in the U.S. & there was a banking holiday in the U.K. Not to mention it is the beginning of summer so things naturally slow down.

Meaning, calling back now in the middle of all of this holiday shuffling might be way too soon.  The 1-3 weeks might come from people simply being away on vacation & such.

I would recommend waiting until next week—Monday specifically—to play it safe.

Also, if they are telling you 1 to 3 weeks, in general you are not going to speed up the process by contacting them to ask what is up after a little more than 1 week. Best to play it cool & contact after 2 weeks in my humble opinion. If they will get back to you in 1-3 weeks you need to wait for them. If they like you they will hire you. If you just call all the time, you actually muddle your chances.

Comment: Canada and there was no holiday last week.

Comment: You asked me the country hence mentioned but thanks for responding. Check my question edit. I missed telling that part.

Comment: thats true and I havent sent them anything other than a thank you note so I am portraying 'calm' to them.

Comment: The thank you note was a good idea, and is all you should normally do unless they're taking longer than they predicted to get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

My general course of action in this type of scenario has always been to make contact, but only to express your thanks for the consideration and the interview, and your excitement at the prospect of working for their company. The benefit of this approach is that you get to establish contact again, hopefully putting yourself back at the top of someone's mind again, while not seeming to ignore that you were told it could be several weeks. You aren't contacting to directly ask for information, but you may receive information as a benefit of reestablishing contact.

On a related note, I had several "sure thing" interviews before landing my current role (5 years ago), and none of them panned out. I would definitely take Wren's advice and continue to act as though you are in need of a job.